# How do I grab a variable from a file and make it global?

Tags: java, global-variables

```java
class vars{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            File tokenFile = new File("./TOKEN");
            final Scanner token = new Scanner(tokenFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Make a file name \"TOKEN\" and put your token in it");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            File prefixFile = new File("./PREFIX");
            final Scanner prefix = new Scanner(prefixFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            final String prefix = "-- ";
        }

        final long Creator = ******************L; // ----
        final long[] Dev = {******************L, ******************L, ******************L}; // -----, ----, ------

    }
}


public class discordbot extends ListenerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("\nJDA version: " + JDAInfo.VERSION + "\n");
        try {

            EnumSet<GatewayIntent> intents = EnumSet.of(
                    GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES,
                    GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
                    GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
                    GatewayIntent.GUILD_INVITES,
                    GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS
            );

            JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(vars.main().token, intents)
                    .addEventListeners(new discordbot())
                    .setActivity(Activity.watching("out for the summons"))
                    .setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE)
                    .enableCache(CacheFlag.VOICE_STATE)
                    .disableCache(CacheFlag.EMOTE)
                    .build();
            jda.awaitReady();
            System.out.println("\nJDA is ready.\n");

        } catch (LoginException loginerror) {

            System.out.println("\nSomething went wrong with authentication.\n");
            loginerror.printStackTrace();

        } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {

            System.out.println("\nJDA got interrupted.\n");
            interrupted.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

I'm trying to use the `token` variable in the JDA builder, but I can't seem to be able to make it into a global variable. I have a lot of functions that use these variables.

I can see them working if I just made them hard-coded, but since I'm planning to distrubute this when I'm done, it needs this type of flexibilty.

Sorry if the question looks bad, I'm not quite the questiong expert.

Comment: You could use an enum, or you could use a static final variable.

Comment: @NomadMaker Could you link me an example of enum? I've just started using Java and don't know what that is or does.

Comment: Guide to enums: https://www.baeldung.com/a-guide-to-java-enums
(in response to your question to NomadMaker)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: **THIS DOES NOT WORK**

First make the variables global:

```java
class vars{

    public enum Global {
        token,
        prefix,
        Creator,
        Dev
    }

}
```

Then just set the variables elsewhere:

```java
class vars{

    public enum Global {
        token,
        prefix,
        Creator,
        Dev
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner rawToken = null;
        try {
            File tokenFile = new File("./TOKEN");
            token = new Scanner(tokenFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Make a file name \"TOKEN\" and put your token in it");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            File prefixFile = new File("./PREFIX");
            Scanner prefix = new Scanner(prefixFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            final String prefix = "-- ";
        }

        final long Creator = ******************L; // ----
        final long[] Dev = {******************L, ******************L, ******************L}; // -----, ----, ------


}
```

Now use can use them anywhere by calling `vars.Global.token` and etc.

EDIT: **THIS DOES NOT WORK**